# Xcode 7 beta - build error (xcassets)

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode7

I was just install Xcode 7 beta and converted my Swift project with Swift 2 guidelines.

Build is OK but xcassets: I reached this error in logs:

```
CompileAssetCatalog /Users/phoenix/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{...}/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/{...}.app {...}/Images.xcassets
cd /Users/phoenix/Dev/Xcode/{...}
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text\
    --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/phoenix/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{...}/Build/Intermediates/{...}.build/Debug-iphoneos/{...}.build/assetcatalog_dependencies.txt
    --output-partial-info-plist /Users/phoenix/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{...}/Build/Intermediates/{...}.build/Debug-iphoneos/{...}.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist\
    --app-icon AppIcon --launch-image LaunchImage --compress-pngs\
    --enable-on-demand-resources YES --target-device iphone --target-device ipad\
    --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --platform iphoneos --compile\
    /Users/phoenix/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{...}/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/{...}.app\
    /Users/phoenix/Dev/Xcode/{...}/Images.xcassets
/Users/phoenix/Dev/Xcode/{...}/Images.xcassets: error:
    Failed to find a suitable device for the type SimDeviceType : com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2 with runtime SimRuntime :
    9.0 (13A4254u) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0
Failure Reason: Failed to create new simulator device that matches SimDeviceType :
    com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2 for runtime SimRuntime :
    9.0 (13A4254u) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-0 ((null))
```

UPD:
Now when I try to launch iOS Simulator from "Open developer tools" menu from dock I reach this error:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded:
    @rpath/SimulatorKit.framework/Versions/A/SimulatorKit
Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Conte‌​nts/MacOS/Simulator
Reason: image not found
```

UPD2:
When trying launch simulator from terminal got warning:

```
$ Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator 
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @loader_path/../../../../Library/PrivateFrameworks in /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator being ignored in restricted program because of @loader_path
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SimulatorKit.framework/Versions/A/SimulatorKit
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
  Reason: image not found
```

I think this is a main issue...

Comment: Rebooted Xcode, iOS Simulator and Mac (if necessary)?

Comment: @LinusG., Xcode was restarted a number of times... iOS simulator cannot be restarted 'cause it not starts... OK, now I'll try to restart mac.

Comment: Yeah if that doesn't work try to reinstall Xcode. If you still have the .dmg then that should not be a problem.

Comment: @LinusG. reboot was not resolved an issue. Simulator still crash, and build still failing. So, will try to reinstall Xcode...

Comment: @LinusG. so, reinstalling was not help. I tried to install Xcode beta at another Mac, and it works OOB with simulators and building. So I not understand difference...

Comment: That is really weird. Are you running OS X beta?

Comment: @LinusG. no, both OS X (at work, where Xcode beta works normal, and at home) is 10.10.3 Yosemite.

Comment: Do you notice any differences in the machines?

Comment: No, configurations is equal (instead at home I have Mac Pro, but Mac Mini at work). Usernames, installed software versions/sources and another things is equal.

Comment: This really is weird. Maybe you should try to reinstall OS X as i think that might cause the problem.

Comment: I would try to run it on an actual device. This looks like a simulator issue. Try reinstalling the simulators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Navigate to `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`, then remove the runtime - the runtime is old. After, reboot Xcode7, and launch the Simulator...

Further explanation from [@seancook](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11706?sr=stream&ru=8243):

> I experienced this, too, on El Capitan. NIBs wouldn't load, no Sims
>   present, and unable to launch Simulators through the Xcode/Open
>   Developer Tool/Simulator menu. After fighting it for a few hours I've
>   finally got it working.
>
> Here's what worked for me (YMMV):   I
>   noticed a message in Console.app along the lines of the Simulator
>   runtime not being code signed. I went to the path it described
>   "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes" and removed the
>   runtimes that I had there. They were old runtimes, so I assume that
>   some check in Xcode now applies that didn't previously. Who knows?
>
> After doing this, I could *finally* launch the Simulator via the
>   Xcode/Open Developer Tool menu. Unfortunately, the Simulator still
>   wasn't being shown as a run target in my workspace, so I kept
>   spelunking...
>
> I then went into the Simulator's Hardware/Devices/Manage Devices menu and added a new iOS9 device. It didn't seem to do anything, so I quit out of Xcode and Simulator.app.
>   I then re-started Simulator.app (via Xcode/ODT/Simulator) and lo and
>   behold the expected iOS9 simulators were displayed.   I closed and
>   re-opened Xcode, changed the target OS for my project, and the Sims
>   were finally displayed as run targets.

Comment: This worked for me! I am assuming this issue cropped up for me after trying to remove files after running out of space.

Comment: Wish I could edit my previous comment but I wanted to mention that I had to completely restart my computer after downloading the new Simulator runtimes within Xcode for things to start working correctly again.

Answer (score 5):

I was using an older xCode ( I have 8.3.1 installed by appstore and I was using 8.2.1).
For me, the solution was Xcode/Preferences>Locations and setting Command Line Tools: Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002) (it was on the newer Xcode before)

Answer (score 2):

I just cleared the derived data and it works fine now.